# import module after pip3 install datalog

Tags: python, import, pip, installation, python-import

After cloning https://github.com/SeanDS/datalog , I installed the module by **pip3 install datalog**.
But when I try to Import the module by

```
from picolog import PicoLogAdc24
```

the result is: *No module named 'PicoLogAdc24'*.

Do I Need the full path here for importing the class PicoLogAdc24, because my current project is in another Directory. I just thought after pip install I don´t need the path.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: if you cloned  it u can install it via `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/SeanDS/datalog/blob/master/datalog/adc/hrdl/picolog.py

```
from datalog.adc.hrdl.picolog import PicoLogAdc24
```